# End of turn special powers

Tags: small-world

Just a bit of confusion associated with how exactly the end of the turn would be scored.

Let's say hypothetically I start with ghouls+spirits and put them into decline and get wizards+forest as my next combination.

When counting points, would ghouls standing on a forest receive a point or is this exclusive to the wizards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The race and power combination is not tied to your other races. So the forest points only count for the wizards in your example.

Answer (score 10):

Your Active race and your In Decline race(s) are scored independently of each other. A race's Special Power only applies to that race. From the rulebook (section II, p8):

> Each Special Power badge gives a unique benefit **to the race it is
>   associated with.**

(emphasis added)

Comment: Also note that with a few exceptions, the special power badge is inactive when they go into decline. This largely depends on the special power badge itself (what appears when you flip over the badge and race when the race is in decline.)